# How to analyze elastic net fitted model coefficients

Tags: r, logistic, feature-selection, elastic-net

**SOLVED**: an elastic net model, as any other logistic regression model, will not generate more coefficients than input variables. Check Zach's answer to understand how from an (apparent) low number of inputs, more coefficients can be generated. The cause of this question was a code bug, as the users pointed out.

This is a simple question. I've fitted a model with 1334 variables using elastic net to perform feature selection and regularization. I'm now trying to interpret the obtained coefficients in order to find correlations between the input variables and the output. The only problem is that instead of the (expected) 1335 coefficients (intercept+1334), extracting the coefficients through `coef(model,s="lambda.min")` yields around 1390 coefficients. This seems highly counterintuitive and stops me from mapping a single coefficient to a single input variable, so I suppose I'm not understanding some of the insides of the elastic net. Any idea would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

PS: just in case someone wonders so, I've not included interaction terms nor any synthetic variable, just the original 1334 ones.

PS2: elastic net references:

- Mathematical paper: http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/B67.2%20(2005)%20301-320%20Zou%20&%20Hastie.pdf
- R package tutorial: http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html

PS3: about the code used to fit the model:

it is a 250 line script, so unless you specifically need it, I think it'd only clutter the question. Basically, the algorithm takes as an input a data frame of 1393 colums, where the last one is the target variable and the first 1392 are the input variables. So, after separating those into two matrices, input and output, the actual model fitting is done in this call:

`cv.glmnet(x=input_matrix,y=output_matrix,family="binomial",type.measure="auc")`

If you need to, I can actually generate a reproducible file with the data I use and the whole script.

Comment: Can you put a reference to a paper or such showing what you mean by "elastic net"?

Comment: Sure, there you go!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a coding issue, not a statistical one. Post the code you're using to fit the model.

Comment: I've added a code excerpt (I'm afraid it's not going to be very informative, though).

Comment: @jmnavarro You need to post more than an excerpt.  You need to post a data sample and code that reproduces the problem EXACTLY.

Comment: ok, I'm working on it. I will post it asap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very likely you have some categorical variables in your input dataset that are being converted to dummy variables.  For example, here is a model with four x variables: "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal,Width", and "Species", and one y variable: "Sepal.Length"

```
library(glmnet)
data(iris)
x <- model.matrix(Sepal.Length~., iris)[,-1]
y <- iris$Sepal.Length
m <- cv.glmnet(x, y)
```

Surprisingly, we get 6 coefficients, instead of the expected 5:

```
>coef(m, m$lambda.min)
6 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                           1
(Intercept)        2.1670759
Sepal.Width        0.5032347
Petal.Length       0.8137398
Petal.Width       -0.3127065
Speciesversicolor -0.6763395
Speciesvirginica  -0.9595409
```

However, after some investigation we realize the number of coefficients matches the number of columns in our input matrix:

```
> nrow(coef(m, m$lambda.min)) == ncol(x) + 1
[1] TRUE
```

Furthermore, this is the same number of coefficients we get from a glm model:

```
> t(t(coef(glm(Sepal.Length~., data=iris))))
                        [,1]
(Intercept)        2.1712663
Sepal.Width        0.4958889
Petal.Length       0.8292439
Petal.Width       -0.3151552
Speciesversicolor -0.7235620
Speciesvirginica  -1.0234978
```

/edit: Here is and example with binary data.  Note that the glmnet model produces the same number of coefficients as a glm model, and both of them produce the expected number of coefficients.  Check your code with a glm.  Also note that both of these examples were reproducible: if there WAS a bug present in `glmnet` (or worse yet `glm`) my example code would provide the package authors (or the core R team) the first step in identifying and fixing the bug.

```
#Setup a glmnet problem
set.seed(42)
ncol <- 10
nrow <- 1000
x <- matrix(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), ncol*nrow, replace=TRUE), ncol=ncol)
cf <- runif(ncol(x)) * sample(0:1, ncol(x), replace=TRUE)
y <- rowSums(x %*% cf) + runif(nrow(x))/10
y <- matrix(as.integer(y>=mean(y)), ncol=1)

#Fit the model
m <- cv.glmnet(x=x,y=y,family="binomial",type.measure="auc")
coef(m, m$lambda.min)
```

Check the number of coefficients

```
> nrow(coef(m, m$lambda.min)) == ncol(x) + 1
[1] TRUE
```

Check the number of coefficients from a glm

```
> nrow(coef(m, m$lambda.min)) == length(coef(glm(y~., data=data.frame(y,x), family='binomial')))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Allegedly, it shouldn't be the case. All my inputs are binary, just TRUE or FALSE. But I will check it just in case.

Comment: @jmnavarro Please post an example matrix of binary data that generates more coefficients than expected.  Until you do so, I (and everyone else on this site) will assume you just have a bug in your code.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do. First of all, I converted my input matrix into a model.matrix and the dimensions are still the same, 1393 variables, so it doesn't seem to be the case of categorical variables with several values. Apart from that, I already stated in a previous comment I'm trying to generate the sample case and in any place I've stated I believe it NOT to be a bug, so you are right to assume whatever you want, but I'd be thankful if you toned down the comments. I'm really thankful for your help, but if it annoys you to do so, then don't do it, but, please, don't be pushy.

Comment: @jmnavarro I see your updates to the question, and appreciate them.  See if you can distill your script down to the essence of the problem.  Can you reproduce it with a subset of the columns from your original dataset?  Can you reproduce it with a subset of rows from your original dataset? Can you reproduce it with a simulated dataset in a fresh R session?  It's hard for us to help you debug your code without being able to run it on our own machines =D

Comment: That's exactly what I'm working on now. Getting rid of everything not important to the problem in the 250-line script and trying to reproduce the outcome. I'll come back asap. Of course, I don't want you to debug any code I haven't posted. Now that the bug possiblity seems the more feasible one, it's when I'm trying to produce a small, concise, reproducible code.

Comment: @jmnavarro Sounds good!

Comment: It, indeed, looks like a preprocessing bug and not an elastic net related problem, so I'm giving you the green tick for the effort and the whole categorical-with-more-than-two values thing I didn't know about. It's a useful fact to know. Thanks for your time!